# SharePoint opening all links in lightbox

Tags: 2013, 2010, site-collection, upgrade

I upgraded a site collection from 2010 to 2013. If I click on item in any list or library then it opens it in lightbox instead of regular browser window where I can see its URL.

Normally item URL is DispForm.aspx?ID=34

In 2010 all links are opening in current window and the problem is only in 2013. For e.g. if you open www.stackoverflow.com and click on any link on page, it will load new page in same window. But in my case SharePoint 2013 is opening them in a lightbox.
There is a feature called "Minimal Download Strategy" which I thought might be creating problem but it is not activated.

What to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has nothing to do with the MDS.

This is in the libraries advanced settings, in the modal section. The default value is Yes, set it to No.